# Access Database 2010 Redistributable for SSDT (x32) and SQL Agent (x64)?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-data-tools

I have SSDT for VS2017 (which is 32-bit) and I created an SSIS project that reads from an Excel file.

I installed the 32-bit [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable][1] to test the SSIS job within SSDT VS2017 and it works fine.

I then created a `sql server agent` job for running the job. I get error `The requested OLE DB provider Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 is not registered` since it's being run in SQL Server 2016 x64 on Windows Server 2019 Standard x64. I uninstalled the 32-bit Access 2010 redistributable and installed the x64 version. Now it runs from sql server agent.

Unfortunately, running it from VS 2017 will generate error `The requested OLE DB provider Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 is not registered`.

How can I use one driver to run in both SSDT and SQL Server agent? I changed `Run64bitRuntime` to true, but I still get the driver error.

Comment: Are you running the SSIS package in Visual Studio ON the server?

Comment: If you can't install both the 32 and 64 at the same time.  Install the 32 bit.  In your agent job step setup, tab "configuration", then "Advanced", there is a check box "32-bit runtime".  Check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the 32 bit driver on the server, and tell the server to run the package in 32 bit mode. Unfortunately that's *still* the only way as far as I know. This has been one of the biggest pains for SSIS developers for over a decade. Welcome to the club!